# Developer mode enable js merging

Tags: magento2, optimization, developer-mode, speedoptimization

I searched for an answer, but I didn't find one.
I like to enable `js` merging and compressing in `Magento 2` developer mode.
Is this possible?
I enabled them in admin, but the merging is not working
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I never tried to do anything like this, but the magento mode, before js merging, seems to be detected at:

`vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/MergeService.php` line `84`

Actually it also seems to do some merging stuff in developer mode, but on a different way.
In developer mode it merges js files by:
`Magento\Framework\View\Asset\MergeStrategy\Checksum`

In all other modes the js files are merged by:
`Magento\Framework\View\Asset\MergeStrategy\FileExists`

Means in developer mode, it compares all the files it wants to merge, to some other file, where it stores the last modified time of the files to merge. And only  if files were modified, the merging will be done.

For further information about how merging of JS/CSS works, this link is kinda helpful, it also explains how to set it up and where limitations are.
https://mirasvit.com/knowledge-base/how-to-combine-javascript-files-in-magento-2.html

---

**JS Bundling:**

The thing, which does only work in production mode is not the JS merging, but the JS bundling. Here is the official Magento doc about JS bundling:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/js-bundling.html

there the mode is detected inside the `createStaticJsAsset` method of `vendor/module-require-js/Model/FileManager.php`. Feel free to try to implement an plugin for this method, and share with us if there were more steps to achieve JS bundling in developer mode.